# JasperReports Studio-Sorting HashMap and error "Collectors cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, java-stream, jasper-reports

I'm collecting the data as a key set in a HashMap and then at the end of the Report I want to sort the HashMap, so I get the top 10 values displayed in a Pie chart.

Because Jasper reports doesn't use the generic equivelant of Java classes, I had to cast and recast etc leading up to

```
((java.util.Set)($V{Variable_1}.entrySet())).stream().sorted((k1, k2) -> ((Integer)((Map.Entry)k1).getValue()).compareTo(((Integer)((Map.Entry)k2).getValue()))).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue))
```

but it fails to compile with error "Collectors cannot be resolved".
I've tried many different variations but the error persists

Any ideas? thanks

PS I don't want to use a TreeMap because I want to sort on value,which contains duplicates.

Comment: Please also include jasper report and your java version, even better if you can provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `"Collectors cannot be resolved"`  -  Did you add import? Or did you try to use fully-qualified name?

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that you can't use an expression like HashMap<Integer,Integer> = ((java.util.Set)($V{Variable_1}.entrySet()).... and the rest,so the collector at then end can't infer what type is should return.

Comment: But does JasperReports Studio work with generic types?

Comment: [Support for Java 1.5 Generics](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/2649)

Comment: @alexk I see,thanks